# What is a good approach for replacing simple regular expressions with custom parsers?

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I'm writing a program for some data processing in C#, and after doing a bit of profiling I've found that the regular expressions I use are the biggest bottleneck. They take up about 80% of the time of the whole algorithm, which does way more than just parsing, so I've decided to parse the data manually instead.

The format is rather simple, I'm basically parsing simple arithmetic expressions in the form of `=XXX+YYY`, where `XXX` and `YYY` are terms, and the `+` represents one of a finite set of operators that can be applied to those terms. There are always only two terms and one operator, though the terms could be represented in a few different ways.

My approach so far has been to basically write a regexp that would be something like `(matchXXX)([+-*/...])(matchYYY)` and then apply another regexp on each of the operands to see what type they are. I don't really have that much experience with writing high performance parsers. I only ever used Parsec in Haskell, which has quite a unique approach, and would probably take a lot of work to implement.

**The question is then, what would be a good way to write a parser for this kind of expressions? Is there a general approach that works well in most cases?**

I'm not looking for a parser generator. What I need is a simple solution that can be implemented manually.

Update: The slowest regexp is currently `([A-Z]+\d+)([+\-*/])([A-Z]+\d+)`

Comment: Why not just use the `String.Split` method, passing the finite set of chars as delimiters?

Comment: Could you show your regex, if it's not too complex?

Comment: Regexes can get slow if you fall into [traps](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) but they can also be fast when optimized. Also, don't forget to use `RegexOptions.Compiled`. Post your regex so we can see if it has issues.

Comment: @Dmitry I could do that if there was a way to see on which character the split occured, but looking at the API, it doesn't seem to be an option there.

Comment: If you need an operator's `char` too, try to use the `String.IndexOfAny` and the `String.Substring`.

Answer (score 2):

The first line of attack that I would try is optimizing the regular expression itself. Since the structure of your expression lacks nesting, there may be a simple optimization that significantly reduces the time taken by the engine.

The next thing I would try is using regex engine better by pre-compiling the expressions, i.e. using non-static methods of `Regex`, rather than the static ones.

In neither of these approaches works, I would go for a simple [recursive descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser). These parsers are the simplest by far to code up, but they give a good performance for simple languages (and your language is definitely simple).

Answer (score 0):

Do you use backreferencing at all? If not -- great, you can optimize it by using faster regex engine. Read more in excellent article here: [Regular Expression Matching Can Be Simple And Fast](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html).

Since your most complex regex does not use it I hope this is the case for the others. And the next step -- do you know your regexes in advance, or they come as input? If the former -- precompile them.

I wrote multi regex engine myself (part of my [NLT suite](https://sourceforge.net/projects/naivelangtools/)) but it is still kind of fresh -- anyway it shows the idea, take all regexes you use, compile them, build a transition table, and run it against the input. Since the table has transitions for **all** regexes, there is no time spent on thinking maybe this, maybe that. After replacing .Net regexes with my MRE I got x2 speed-up (I said it, it is fresh :-D).